Which is the most convinent company to rent a car from at Copenhagen Airport
Is there any of the rental car services operation at Copenhagen Airport which would allow for a convenient car return near the check-in counters or the kiss and wave area?
It looks like all rental car returns are done on the Tårnby side of the airport, next to the old domestic terminal, and then using shuttle buses to ferry passengers the terminals. Since I'm traveling with a child and full luggage any extra transfer will be inconvenient.

What did the car rental companies say when you contacted them about this?

If you don't need to travel to a location outside of their "Zone", GreenMobility (a car-sharing service) has reserved parking spaces in the P7 garage, "only a 3-minute walk from Terminal 3".

If you search on Google Maps, it'll show you the locations of all the sites; Thrifty appears to be closest to the terminal, but there's not much difference. But there are many factors governing convenience, and personal circumstances will dictate whether it's better to walk some distance or get a shuttle bus.

@MichaelSeifert I need to travel outside of the zone so I asked about rental

Expedia (and equivalent) allows you to sort search results by "pick up location": either "Terminal" or "Free Shuttle" . They list several companies at the Terminal: (Budget, Avis, Alamo, Enterprise, ...)
and others as "Shuttle": (Sixt Fox, Hertz). I don't know whether this is accurate or just meaningless marketing lies. Google Maps shows both Avis and Hertz at the same location. You can try calling, but even then call center might not know or give you the wrong information just to make a sell.

It's quite possible that a lot of the information was not updated since Terminal 1 closed, even though that was nearly a decade ago! That's the case on some of the rental companies websites at least.
